# A action is seemingly overwriting another unrelated slice

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I'm not quite sure how to explain this, but here is a picture that could help explain the issue that I seem to be facing.

[image]

As you can see, I have a `SharedNotificationsModule` and a `SharedConversationsModule`, these are totally separate to one another and each contain their own state files.

I am importing the `SharedNotificationsModule` into my `SharedHeaderModule` as this is where the majority of notification related content will be.

However, if I navigate to the `ConversationsPage` and the `LOAD_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS` is triggered my previous `notifications` slice is being overwritten.

This isn't only happening on the `LOAD_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS` action, this happens on other pages but some times the action that get's the user or the action that get's a users profile (when navigating to the users profile page).

I'm not sure what/if any code you would like to see, but just let me know what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out now, turns out that I had forgotten to add a `default` to the switch in my `notificationsReducer`. The default now just returns the existing state.

```
default: 
    return state;
```